# How can I redirect an url if it contains specific characters

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to redirect (301) these urls:

```
c-4344196/springkussen-in-gorinchem/
c-4375489/springkussen-in-schiedam/
c-4532389/springkussen-in-rotterdam/
c-4339304/springkussen-in-spijkenisse/
```

etc to:

```
verhuur/springkussen-in-gorinchem/
verhuur/springkussen-in-schiedam/
verhuur/springkussen-in-rotterdam/
verhuur/springkussen-in-spijkenisse/
```

But my problem is, I already have this line:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ product-page.php?cat=$1&alias=$2 [QSA,L]
```

That line send everything/everything to product-page.php, that would mean verhuur/springkussen-in-rotterdam would also be rewritten to that file, instead of 301 redirected to one my above examples.

I thought about only redirecting when the url begins with `c-` but I am not sure if this is possible or how to achieve this.

So c-(everything)/springkussen-in-gorinchem/ should redirect to verhuur/springkussen-in-gorinchem/

I've tried the following:

First:

```
#LP
RewriteRule ^c-([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ verhuur/(.*)?alias=$2 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

And then:

```
RewriteRule         ^verhuur/(.*) lp.php?alias=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But this shows the following in my url bar:

```
verhuur/(.*)?alias=springkussen-in-schiedam
```

How can I do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^c-[^/]+/(.+)$ /verhuur/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you this redirects to the correct page and the url looks good. Only issue is no data is loaded, so my $_GET['alias'] can't find the alias. Why could that be? I first have this line `RewriteRule         ^verhuur/(.*) lp.php?alias=$1 [QSA,L]` and then your line below it.

Comment: Nevermind I got it, forgot a / behind my rewrite. Thank you!